# WCF Service Security for Authentication and Authorization

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, wcf-security

First of all I apologize for my english...
As I wrote in title I need to secure my WCF Service.
I always used message security mode using ClientCredentialType="Certificate", checking in this way:

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="cn=abc" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName"/>
<clientCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
</clientCertificate>
```

This configuration worked well, but now I need to assign different privileges to the authenticated clients, I need Authorization in other words.
Any idea?
Thanks,
Alberto

Comment: Is this still an open question?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're after Roles. Check out this [Codeplex Chapter](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Ch%2005%20-%20Authentication%2C%20Authorization%20and%20Identities%20in%20WCF) and the Authorization section of the [Codeplex WCF Security Guidelines](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Guidelines). It provides plenty of details of different scenarios and I found it very useful when setting up WCF services.